# How to read files from folder based on column value of dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have column with some numbers , for each number i want to check in folder if this match to any file name in folder read this file ,if not match number go for next ...

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'x':['2000','5000','10000']})
```

files_folder:

```
P2000.csv
P4000.csv
P5000.csv
P6000.csv
P4000.csv
```

result:
read files :

```
P2000.csv
P5000.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `glob` with test substring in `any` with list comprehension:

```
import glob

df=pd.DataFrame({'x':['2000','5000','10000']})

for f in glob.glob('files_folder/*.csv'):
    if any([x in f for x in df['x']]):
        print (f)

files_folder\P2000.csv
files_folder\P5000.csv
```

List comprehension:

```
files = [f for f in glob.glob('files_folder/*.csv') if any([x in f for x in df['x']])]
print (files)
['files_folder\\P2000.csv', 'files_folder\\P5000.csv']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob.glob()` to list all csv files in your `files_folder`. Then use `apply()` to check if value in `x` is in those filename list.

```py
import glob
import numpy as np

files = glob.glob("/path/to/*.csv")

files = df['x'].apply(lambda x: f'P{x}.csv' if any([f'P{x}' in k for k in files]) else np.nan ).dropna().tolist()
```

```
print(files)

['P2000.csv', 'P5000.csv']
```